# Can you pass an enity-framework table/collection as a parameter into a function (asp.net/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

Is this possible?

```
 using (Entities db = new Entities())
 {
   LoadDropDownList(ddlFirst, db.MyTable , (bool)(myMember.Id == 0), (int)myMember.RevenueRangeID);
   LoadDropDownList(ddlSecond, db.OtherTable , (bool)(myMember.Id == 0), (int)myMember.OtherID);

 }
```

I am stumbling on what the type of the second parameter should be - I am essentially trying to pass in the Entity-Framework 'table' into a generic routine that loads the DropDownList with data from the 'MyTable' table using custom logic/filtering.

SInce I do the same thing about 6 times for 6 different dropdownlist/table combos I wanted to use a generic function to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying type of your tables is [ObjectSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx) (Or DbSet if you're using CodeFirst):

```
public void LoadDropDownList<T>(DropDownList dropDown, ObjectSet<T> table, 
    bool isNew, int otherId)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

```
using(Entities db = new Entities())
{
   LoadDropDownList(ddlReferralType, db.TheTable.ToList(), (bool)(myMember.Id ==0), (int)myMember.RevenueRangeID); 
}
```

This forces the table to be enumerated and converted to a `List<TMyTableEntity>`.  The problem with passing the table directly is that Entity Framework uses deffered execution, meaning the table may not be queried until *after* the ObjectContext (`Entities db`) has already been disposed.

As to what `Type` the `db.TheTable` is, that depends on how you have your EF code-generation configured.  But it's probably either a `ObjectSet<T>` or an `ObjectQuery<T>`.